# Do MySQL databases implement Transactions by Default?

Tags: mysql, transactions

I was wondering what happens when several users try to **UPDATE** a MySQL database at the same time. Went online and learnt about **Transactions**.

Do I need to define the transactions statements.(`START TRANSACTION,... COMMIT/ROLLBACK`) for every one of my database **UPDATE** queries? Is there an automated way to achieve this?

Comment: The default is auto-commit, each query is a single transaction. If you want a transaction across multiple queries, you have to use `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT/ROLLBACK` explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default , MySQL has autocommit enabled, which can be toggled off using
`set session autocommit=off;`
For transaction based queries like banking, manual use of TRANSACTION is executed, which ignores the autocommit setting. e.g:

```
START TRANSACTION;
update bank_card set balance=balance-100;
update credit_card set balance=balance+100;
ROLLBACK; -- execute rollback to cancel the transaction if necessary 
COMMIT;
```

Should something went wrong in any of the UPDATE statements,by executing `ROLLBACK;` the transaction is aborted and no UPDATE is performed.

When several users try to UPDATE the same table, MySQL will place a LOCK on related rows which prevents simultaneous writing. The first UPDATE query will release the lock by either committing (successful) or rolling back (usually something went wrong) before the second update query can acquire the lock and do the UPDATE.

Comment: Is it possible to have other code between the two Queries ? something like:START TRANSACTION;  SELECT balance FROM bank WHERE userId=1; <some other code that depend on the value obtained above> UPDATE users SET balance=balance+100; COMMIT;

Comment: Yes you can. But please avoid  unnecessary statements in a TRANSACTION. You want a single TRANSACTION as short as possible to reduce resource competing time. Based on the level of TRANSACTION ISOLATION system variable, making TRANSACTION too complex could potentially lead to dead lock.